# Little Endian vs Big Endian on Example

Tags: memory, memory-management, endianness

I got these hex number:

0xAF2B and i have to calculate little and big endian.

I got a memory like this: a ; a+1; a+2; a+3.

Can you tell if this is correct?

0xAF2B

1. Little Endian:a = 2B, a+1 = AF, a+2 = 00 , a+3 = 00
2. Big Endian: a = AF, a+1 = 2B, a+2 = 00, a+3 = 00

Answer (score 0):

Little endian is correct. But big endian is incorrect.

Your numbers seem to have 4 bytes, and on 4 bytes, you number is 0x00.00.AF.2B

Hence, on a big endian computer, byte arrangement in memory will be

```
a=0     MSB (big) comes first       
a+1=0  
a+2=AF  
a+3=2B  LSB last
```